# Navigate to a nested route adding more routes to the stack

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-v5

I'm using React Navigation v5 and in order for you to understand my question, this is how my routes are organized:

```
   (Top Stack)
[Root] --- [Chat]
             |          (Chat Stack)
             |---[Chat List] --- [Message List]
```

I want to go from `Root` to `Message List` but I want to add also the `Chat List` to the stack so when the user press the back button it goes back to the `Chat List` instead of the `Root` screen.

Right now I have a solution that is quite hacky, modifying the navigator state, nevertheless, I was wondering if there's a less hacky way to do this, maybe using the navigator function.

This is how I'm doing it right now:

```js
navigationRef.current?.dispatch(() => {
              return CommonActions.reset({
                index: 1,
                routes: [
                  {name: 'Root'},
                  {
                    name: 'Chat',
                    state: {
                      index: 1,
                      routes: [
                        {
                          name: 'ChatList',
                        },
                        {
                          name: 'MessagesList',
                          params: {
                            chatId: pushData?.chatId,
                          },
                        },
                      ],
                    },
                  },
                ],
              });
            });
```

Comment: as I thought, another solution could be custom `onPress` function in `HeaderBackButton` and hardware button to replace the MessageList screen by ChatList?

Comment: @tuan.tran Already tried that and I didn't like that solution because when you go back it transitions using a "Push" animation instead of a "Pop" animation. Do you know a way to overwrite that?

Comment: you should try https://reactnavigation.org/docs/stack-navigator/#animationtypeforreplace